# How can I implement functions in Simulink to generate C code which have macro functions defined?

Tags: matlab, embedded, simulink

I am trying to model an algorithm which needs macro functions to be defined in the auto generated C code using embedded coder. How to do I define functions as macros in Simulink/Stateflow for the same?

Comment: Why does it need macro functions? Do you mean you want to use pre-existing macro functions in your algorithm?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will have one too many function calls if I don't use macro which'd affect the system. I don't have a pre-existing macro functions but want create new ones.

Comment: What do you mean by too many function calls? Are you worried about the performance of the generated code?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. Moreover it needs to be a macro per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you are trying to replace some functions generated by the Simulink models with your own macros. You can probably achieve what you want by creating a code replacement library as described [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/examples/optimize-generated-code-by-developing-and-using-code-replacement-libraries-sc.html).

Also there is a limitation to which functions you can replace: [the list of functions which you can replace](https://se.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/code-you-can-replace-from-simulink-models.html?s_tid=mwa_osa_a).

Another simple but not very elegant solution would be to write a script to do the code replacement manually. You can write a custom hook to call the script after the code is generated ([customizing the build process](https://se.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/customizing-the-target-build-process-with-the-stf-make-rtw-hook-file.html)). I would not recommend editing the generated code unless you are sure what you are doing though.

Comment: Since I am quite new in stackoverflow, I would appreciate the constructive feedback if you are downvoting my answer.